# Loop JS object data in multiple arrays

Tags: javascript

I have some data in a Google Spreadsheet, which I'm pulling with Tabletop.js. I'm able to display my data as well in my showInfo() function. All good.

Now I try to achieve to display this data in a default Google Chart. In this case I use their map package to display my data on a map. They provided me some sample code, [see here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/map).

At the moment I'm struggling with the following function, whole code in [my Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kleefaan/8ykdwuky/):

```
mapdata.addRows([
    // PREFERRED DATA TO COLLECT:
    // [data.geoloc, data.GM_NAAM, 'blue' ],
    // THE HARDCODED WAY:
    ['Kerkbrink 2 ANLOO', 'ANLOO', 'green'],
    ['Grote Kerkstraat 32 WIJK EN AALBURG', 'WIJK EN AALBURG',  'blue']
  ]);
```

How do I approach? I managed to display all data with a forEach in the showInfo function, but this does not work in this array.

I'm pretty new in JS-land, so I appreciate every help on achieving this.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: could you provide the mysterious `showInfo` result?

Comment: _"whole code in my Fiddle"_ should be a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/) in the question itself

Comment: Excuse me, updated my fiddle.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

please find the updated fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/8ykdwuky/5/)

is this what you are looking for ?

updated js code:

```
/* 1: tabletop shizzle */

var publicSpreadsheetUrl = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cpSdKrQK0DfRoC9_xgmAqwVaDqw8BKMOL7drA_QFIn0/edit?usp=sharing';

function init() {
  Tabletop.init( { key: publicSpreadsheetUrl,
                   callback: showInfo,
                   simpleSheet: true } )
}

function showInfo(data, tabletop) {
 alert('Successfully processed!')

  var chartdiv = document.querySelector(".chart_div");
  console.log("data: ", data);
  data.forEach( function(data) {

    // card
    var card = document.createElement('div');
    card.classList.add("card");

    //content
    var content = document.createElement('div');
    content.classList.add('content');
    content.innerHTML = data.GM_NAAM + ' ' + data.geoloc;

    // append
    chartdiv.appendChild(card);
    card.appendChild(content);
  });
// trigger the google charts drapMap function and send the data to it
    drawMap(data);
}
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init);



/* 2: google chart shizzle */

google.charts.load('current', {
  'packages': ['map'],
  // DEFAULT GOOGLE API KEY
  'mapsApiKey': 'AIzaSyD-9tSrke72PouQMnMX-a7eZSW0jkFMBWY'
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawMap);

function drawMap(data) {

  var mapdata = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  mapdata.addColumn('string', 'Address');
  mapdata.addColumn('string', 'Location');
  mapdata.addColumn('string', 'Marker')

  console.log(data);
  data = data ? data : [];
  var rows = [];
  data.forEach(function(item){
    rows.push([item.GM_NAAM, item.geoloc, 'green'])
  })
  // THIS IS THE PART I NEED THE DATA.
  mapdata.addRows(rows);


  // SOME OPTIONS
  var url = 'https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/icons-land/vista-map-markers/48/';

  var options = {
    zoomLevel: 7,
    showTooltip: true,
    showInfoWindow: true,
    useMapTypeControl: true,
    icons: {
      blue: {
        normal:   url + 'Map-Marker-Ball-Azure-icon.png',
        selected: url + 'Map-Marker-Ball-Right-Azure-icon.png'
      },
      green: {
        normal:   url + 'Map-Marker-Push-Pin-1-Chartreuse-icon.png',
        selected: url + 'Map-Marker-Push-Pin-1-Right-Chartreuse-icon.png'
      }
    }
  };
  var map = new google.visualization.Map(document.getElementById('map_div'));

  map.draw(mapdata, options);
}
```